# Changing ID on an ipad 2?

Tags: ipad

I am using IOS 7 ipad 2. I have no longer got access to the email associated with my ipad when I bought it so I have changed my iTunes id to a new email address but cannot seem to shift the old email address which my ipad keeps asking for. Help!! How do I get my ipad to accept the new id. I can't switch off "Find my ipad" because it wont let me as it keeps asking for the password  for the old id which is goodness knows what. I need some serious help!!

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you have access to your email does not affect your Apple ID, except that you cannot receive marketing emails. To answer your question, you must go to Settings>iTunes and App Store, sign out and then sign back in. You can also reset your password or change your email at:
https://appleid.apple.com

Once you have access to your account, you can log into iCloud and remove that device from Find My iPhone if it shows as offline or just remove Find My iPhone from the Settings app.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I carried out part one of your instruction and it worked. Excuse my thickness but could you expand on how to go about changing icloud? Thanks in expectation!

Comment: If you log in to iCloud with the new Apple ID and go to Find My iPhone and the iPad shows as offline (which it will most likely do) you can just remove it. Make sure that (on the iPad) you go to Settings>Mail, Contacts and Calendar>[your iCloud account] and turn on Find My iPhone under the new account.